# The sum of consecutive strings of positive integers of length $2*n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Let $a(n)$ is the sum of consecutive strings of positive integers of length $2*n$, starting with the integer $2$; and $a(0) = 1$.

So, we'll have strings like below:
$5=2+3$;
$22=4+5+6+7$;
$63=8+9+10+11+12+13$; etc.

I know that according to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A288534) $a(n)=n(2n^2+3)$, but I am not sure how to prove it.
I thought about geometrical approach to get the formula.
Any hints are highly welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by trying to find a formula for the last digits of the $n$th series. The last digits are $1, 1+2*1, 1+2*1+2*2, ...$ which you can see is equal to
$$1+\sum_{k=1}^n 2k= 1+2\sum_{k=1}^n k=1+n(n+1)$$
(look up triangular numbers if you don’t understand the last step).

$a(n)$ is equal to the sum of the integers less than or equal to the $n$th last digit, minus the sum of the integers less than or equal to the $n-1$st last digit. In other words, the $1+n(n+1)$st triangular number minus the $1+n(n-1)$st triangular number, which is equal to
$$(1+n(n+1))(2+n(n+1))/2-(1+n(n-1))(2+n(n-1))/2$$
and simplifies to the formula you found.